# How to forward an email containing multiple threads with multiple pictures in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

I have an email thread I would like to forward. The email thread has a bunch of replies each with pictures.

I can forward and select "include original attachments", but that only includes the images on the most recent reply. Every previous attachment still looks like `<PastedGraphic-14.png>`. Is there anyway to forward an email including all the actual images?

Comment: It may be worth you including whether this is on a Mac, iPhone etc? Also, the version of OS you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mail** does not have the ability to search through an email thread and automatically reinsert stripped photos in-place. Doing so would likely result in emails too large to either send or receive (not to mention the amount of development effort involved in implementing such logic).

Your options are:

1. Go and find every “missing” photo yourself, save them to your desktop (macOS) or camera roll (iOS) then manually attach them all to your forwarded email.
2. Select each individual email that contains photos, then click **Message** → **Forward as Attachment** from the menu bar (also available from the right-click menu). This solution requires a Mac.

Comment: Aww that's what I was afraid of. I'm coming from the Outlook world so I'm used to that feature. Okay thanks.

Comment: I believe for a few versions (iOS 9.x), iOS Mail did include images in replies. You got the option of choosing picture quality on every reply. That behavior has since been reverted, however. I too enjoyed Outlook’s behavior, even if it only includes a down-sampled version of photos from previous emails.